# Problem with Leaflet Boundary Canvas plugin

Tags: gdal, leaflet, gdal2tiles

I'm trying to identify the source of a problem that I'm having, I cannot show a tile layer(created with gdal2tiles) inside a polygon generated in Leaflet, using the plug-in BoundaryCanvas(https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas)

**Some facts:**

- The tile layer created with Gdal2tiles.py, can be shown in the map with Leaflet if I just use the object tileLayer. From this I understand that the tile layer was generated correctly.
- If I use the object tileLayer.BoundaryCanvas(with boundary a polygon), the tile is not shown and in the browser there are errors missing PNG files(it's trying to download png's that are not in the path structure of the tile layer).
- If I use the same plug-in with for example the TMS from OSM http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png, it works properly I can show that tile
  inside the polygon.

At this point I don't know if the errors comes from the Leaflet plug-in or from the tile layer generation.

**I'm using:**

```
gdal2tiles.py --profile=geodetic -z 0-15 -w none ./terra.tif
```

**gdalinfo**

Driver: `GTiff/GeoTIFF`

Files: `TerraColor_SanFrancisco_US_15m.tif`

Size is `7204 x 7204`

Coordinate System is:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Origin = (-122.809804036593036,38.285436652047451)
Pixel Size = (0.000138800000000,-0.000138800000000)
```

Metadata:

```
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
```

Image Structure Metadata:

```
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
```

Corner Coordinates:

```
Upper Left  (-122.8098040, 38.2854367) (122d48'35.29"W, 38d17' 7.57"N)
Lower Left  (-122.8098040, 37.2855215) (122d48'35.29"W, 37d17' 7.88"N)
Upper Right (-121.8098888, 38.2854367) (121d48'35.60"W, 38d17' 7.57"N)
Lower Right (-121.8098888, 37.2855215) (121d48'35.60"W, 37d17' 7.88"N)
Center      (-122.3098464,  37.7854791) (122d18'35.45"W, 37d47' 7.72"N)
Band 1 Block=7204x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=7204x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=7204x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can see your layer on a map using `L.TileLayer`, the problem is in the boundary polygon you pass in `L.TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas`. It is difficult to guess the exact problem without example sources, but you can try the following checks:

- Add your layer using `L.TileLayer` and your boundary using `L.Polygon` (or using `L.GeoJOSN`). Check that your polygon corresponds to the location of your tiles.
- Check that your boundary has no self-intersections or intersection of holes and outer ring. `L.TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas` can't work with such geometries.

Online example will be very usefull for more concrete answer.